# Inheriting column comments with an FDW

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

I have 2 postgresql database instances and I use fdw to import schemas from one instance to another. However I've seen that my local column comments don't import with schemas. I know that inheritance doesn't preserve constraints, indexes and rights. But I wanted to know if there was a way to keep comments at column level.

I import my schemas like this:

```
import foreign schema nom_schema_local from server nom_server into nom_schema_distant ;
```

Thank you

Comment: That has nothing to do with inheritance. Comments are not copied over. You will have to run individual `COMMENT` statements.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, that's what I thought. And concerning the table names, are they supposed to change automatically when they are modified in the initial instance?

Comment: No, not at all.